# get_data y plot_data ¿de qué módulo python son funciones?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intento utilizar el siguiente script, que utiliza un módulo denominado "util"

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from util import get_data, plot_data

# Read data
dates = pd.date_range("2009-01-01","2012-12-31")
symbols = ["SPY"]
df = get_data(symbols,dates)
plot_data(df)
```

Me devuelve el error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'

Pensando que el módulo "util", podría estar obsoleto para python 3, instalo el módulo "python_utils", y con el mismo script

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from python_utils import get_data, plot_data

# Read data
dates = pd.date_range("2009-01-01","2012-12-31")
symbols = ["SPY"]
df = get_data(symbols,dates)
plot_data(df)
```

obtengo el error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'get_data'

¿En qué módulo Python se encuentran dichas funciones?.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buenas efueyo, por lo que he podido ver el módulo get_data está dentro de [pkutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) y sobre plot_data me sale que está dentro de matplotlib, de todas formas te dejo información que puede venirte bien [pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py) Espero todo esto te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Estas funciones no vienen de un paquete reconocido y están definidas en este tutorial:

https://linuxhint.com/pandas-data-frame-tutorial/

Tendrás que incluirlas en tu script, o si quieres mantener un `util.py`, ponerlas ahí.